# How many 6-input LUTs are necessary to synthesize any 10-variable switching function?

Tags: digital-logic, digital-communications

For example when we need an 8 variable function with 6 input LUT we require 5 LUTs , 
[image: 5 luts]

And hence it seems to me that for 10 variables we would need 3 (as 2 would give cumulative of 6 variables , and the other 4 would be considered independently.BUT the answer is 21. Plz explain!!
[image]
This is what i am thinking currently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the 8-variable case, you need a 256-bit LUT. So you distribute that over four 64-bit LUTs, and use a fifth LUT as a 4:1 multiplexer to select the correct output.

So, for 10 variables, you need 16 of your 64-bit LUTs, and a 16:1 multiplexer, which requires 5 more LUTs.

You can also think of it as four copies of your 8-variable circuit (20 LUTs), with one more 4:1 mux to select the correct output from them.

Comment: yeah, 10 variables is 1024 bits, 6 variables in 64 bits, so you need 16 of them to have the same flexibility and the mux - if you have to build the mux from the same blocks you'd need three more.

Comment: Hello there thanks for the answer ,i updated my question , added a pic to explain what i am thinking , plz tell me where am i wrong